# error that i get in Oracle 11.2

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01830

1.0.6 my program works excellent
but in Oracle 11.2 i get error ORA-01830

what can be the problem ? is there any Difference between 11.1 and 11.2 ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Here is the New Features Guide that describes the main differences: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17128/chapter1.htm

Comment: For the bugfixes in 11.2.0.2 you can look at My Oracle Support "11.2.0.2 Patch Set - List of Bug Fixes by Problem Type [ID 1179583.1]" if you have access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a parameter called `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, which defines how your dates are converted to characters as default. You are probably treating a string as date, and Oracle tries to automatically convert it to date but fails. You may want to set that parameter to the one you used in 11.1;

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='<Your Date Format In 11.1 Here>';
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is:

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends
>   before converting entire input string

So it could be cause by different default date format masks (NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter) in the 2 environments.